# Can `String.length()` be used to see which of two String objects is larger?

Tags: java, string, object, compare, string-comparison

If `String.length()` cannot be used to compare two String objects and determine which object is larger, then what string method would do such a thing? When I run this code it terminates immediately. Is there a method to compare pairs of strings? I'm using the API for the string class as a reference here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

```
public class ThingsComparer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String ObjectOne = new String("One");
        String ObjectTwo = new String("Two");

        if (ObjectOne.length() > ObjectTwo.length())
        {
            System.out.println("ObjectOne is larger");
        }
        else if (ObjectOne.length() < ObjectTwo.length())
        {
            System.out.println("ObjectTwo is larger");
        }
        else if (ObjectOne.equals(ObjectTwo)) 
        {
            System.out.println("ObjectOne and ObjectTwo are equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean LONGER or LARGER?

Comment: You can see the method `compareTo` in the doc page, why not use it? If it's not what you're looking for, you'll have to be more clear in what you mean by larger`?

Comment: Yes I am referring to the length so I suppose longer would be the correct wording

Comment: Your third if statement compares the strings, not their length. Your code is otherwise correct,

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: In that case, yes, it can and you pretty much have the idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
.....
.....
 else if (ObjectOne.length() == ObjectTwo.length()) 
    {
        System.out.println("ObjectOne and ObjectTwo are equal");
    }
```

Furthermore, according to Thilo, you don't need `else if (ObjectOne.length() == ObjectTwo.length())` at all specially after you have tried to look for greater and lesser than conditions. What's the 3rd condition? It's equal.

Comment: `length()`, not `length`.

Comment: and I would not call this "equal". They have the same length.

Comment: @Thilo read the last 2 comments in the main post. Thats exactly what he is looking for

Comment: Also, why the `if` at all? should be a simple `else`.

Answer (score 1):

@Peanutcalota

The above code is working fine. The reason that you are not getting any output is that the 2 objects `ObjectOne` and `ObjectTwo` are having different strings and have equal lengths.

So the first and second condition will not work as both are having the same length.

The last condition will not work because both strings are different.

`ObjectOne.equals(ObjectTwo)` will only work if they are having same string.

And I have tried running this program, it is executing fine.

Give it a try.